# create video from images with animation

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I have ten images to create a video with animation , like that
https://youtu.be/iu9uazolcC8

it use freeImage and FFmpeg.

```
    MovieWriter writer(fileName, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
        vector<char*> ls = {
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/1.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/2.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/3.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/4.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/5.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/6.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/7.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/8.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/9.jpg",
 "D:/createVideo/src/c/10.jpg",
};
        FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT pic_type = FIF_JPEG;
        FIBITMAP *fiCopy = NULL;
        FIBITMAP *corpImg = NULL;
        uint8_t *ut = NULL;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            char *src_pic_path = ls[i];

            FIBITMAP *fi = FreeImage_Load(pic_type, src_pic_path);

            if(fi==NULL){
                continue;
            }
            int w = IMG_WIDTH;
            int h = IMG_HEIGHT;
            unsigned int index = 0;

            while (w > IMG_MIN_W_SCALE || h > IMG_MIN_H_SCALE)
            {       
                fiCopy = FreeImage_RescaleRect(fi,  IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,0, 0, w * 2, h * 2);
                if(fiCopy == NULL){
                    break;
                }
                corpImg = FreeImage_Rescale(fiCopy, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
                if(corpImg == NULL){
                    break;
                }
                ut = FreeImage_GetBits(corpImg);
                if(ut == NULL){
                    break;
                }
                w -= ONE_W_PIECE;
                h -= ONE_H_PIECE;
                writer.addFrame(ut);
                FreeImage_Unload(corpImg);
                FreeImage_Unload(fiCopy);
                index++;
            }
        }
```

but it so slowly, how to optimization that code? or how to faster to create that video?

would you know about an option to do that?

Comment: I noticed my origin images file size is 3M , all video frame data szie more than 100M, but the finaly create file size is 3.4M,  the video directly helps me to compress the keyframes. I want to find a way to write directly by setting the keyframes, but I can't find.... I think it should be feasible...maybe some one else know?

Comment: Why do you need to rescale images? I think to rescale image make it slowly.

Comment: Yes ,you right ,because I need to make a scale animation .